# Lost java keystore file and app signing is disabled

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I have lost my key store file and app signing is disabled on my app. **What should i need to do, to reset keystore file and update my app on the play store?** If i enable app signing now then is it possible to reset? **Please help i kind of stuck here.**

Answer (score 0):

You can go [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) and fill the form with the details. You will receive an email from Google Support guiding you to create a new keystore and send it to them. After you send them your new keystore you'll have to wait a week or so before you can upload an update of your app signed with the new key.

Comment: That only works if you have App Signing enabled. The developer here mentions that they have not enrolled in App Signing, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you hadn't enrolled in *App Signing by Play* before, there is nothing you can do now.

To enroll in *App Signing by Play* now, you would still need your keystore.

Your two only options are:

- Find that keystore.
- Create a new app with a different package name.

Sorry :-/